# Pass indexPath via Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, xcode6.1

I am trying to pass the indexPath of a NSManagedObject via a segue (show) so in the destination I can have dynamic information shown. I have tried multiple ways, but have gotten errors for all of them. This is the method I am currently trying, but it is not working. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and/or what the most effective way to do this?

#### numberOfRowsInSection & prepareForSegue code in source View Controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectives.count
}

...

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as ObjectiveDetailViewController
    if segue.identifier == "ObjectiePrototypeCell" {
        controller.indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
    }
}
```

**Error (occurs when calling tableView.indexPathForCell):** '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathForCell'.

Is there something I need to add to the numberOfRowsInSection function?

#### Destination View Controller Code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ObjectiveDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var objectives = [NSManagedObject]()
var indexPath: NSIndexPath?
lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    return managedContext!
    }()

var obj = objectives[indexPath.row]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

**Error (occurs when calling objectives in declaring obj):** 'ObjectiveDetailViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'objectives'.

This error I have no clue what is wrong because I clearly have initiated the objectives array. Have I declared something incorrectly or have I not given enough information?

Comment: `self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)` your `sender` is not `UITableViewCell`, its `UIViewController`, better to have a global variable which stores the selected indexPath, and use it directly.

Comment: @iphonic, if the segue was made from the cell, then the sender will be the cell.

Comment: I cannot see the benefit of passing an `indexPath` (which is related to the tableView) to another view controller. If you want to display information for a specific `NSManagedObject` why don't you pass the `NSManagedObjectID` of the object to your destination view controller? The `NSManagedObjectID` is unique and gives extremely fast access to the object.

Comment: @zisoft Why would I use the `NSManagedObjectID` rather than the `NSManagedObject`. Also, if I was to use the `NSManagedObjectID`, how would I fetch the object associated with that ID?

Comment: I (personally) think it is a better solution to pass the `NSManagedObjedID` rather than a (maybe complex) `NSManagedObject`. The `NSManagedObjectID` can be retrieved from the object by its `objectID` property. In the destination view controller the `NSManagedObject` can then simply be retrieved by calling `NSManagedObjectContext.objectWithId(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the first error (despite that weird error message) has nothing to do with numberOfRowsInSection. Since the sender is a conditional AnyObject, you need to unwrap it, and downcast it:

```
controller.indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender! as UITableViewCell)
```

The second error is caused by accessing your array outside of a method. You should move that line into viewDidLoad (and you need to unwrap indexPath as well),

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var obj = objectives[indexPath!.row]
}
```

There's another problem with that, though, because you haven't added any NSManagedObjects to your array before you try to access it.

Probably, what you want to do though, is to pass the managed object that was selected in the table view, not pass the indexPath.

Comment: Yes, the error message is quite misleading. The compiler seems to assume that `self.tableView` is the `tableView(tableView:, numberOfRowsInSection section:)` *method*.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the `NSManagedObject` rather than the indexPath and am able to do that successfully. My problem now is when when I try to access the object's values using `valueForKey()` I get this error: `'NSManagedObject?' does not have a member named 'valueForKey'`. That doesn't make sense. Can you explain why I may be getting this? You can view the code here: https://github.com/bmorgan296/Practice-Journal.git

Comment: @b.morgan.296 You have several problems. You didn't give the segue an identifier in the storyboard, and you didn't change the class of the detail controller to your custom class. Once again, you need to unwrap conditionals; since objective is a conditional, you must unwrap it, and also use as? (instead of as), so that line should be, title = objective!.valueForKey("name") as? String